# Php: Remove multiple child tags(script)

Tags: php, domdocument

Need to find a single `<script> condition </script>` that contains condition.
The example below contains 4 tags, i need to match the second tag that contains condition and discard the others. Starts with `<script>`. Before the condition could be space or new line, and than the condition like `if (window.location.href == bar) { }` and than could be space or new line, and the end `</script>`.

```
<script>                  <!-- discard --->
other stuff
not to be found
</script>                 


<script>                  <!-- MATCH --->

if (window.location.href == bar) {         
do something                 
}

</script>                

<script>                 <!-- discard --->
other stuff
not to be found
</script>                

<script>                 <!-- discard --->
other stuff
not to be found
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope you were expecting this result.

Answer (score 1):

Here you should use `DOMDocument` instead of `Regex` for matching tags and its required content.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784740)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$object= new DOMDocument();
$object->loadHTML('<html><body><script>                  <!-- discard --->
other stuff
not to be found
</script>                 

<script>                  <!-- MATCH --->

if (window.location.href == bar) {         
do something                 
}

</script>                

<script>                 <!-- discard --->
other stuff
not to be found
</script>                

<script>                 <!-- discard --->
other stuff
not to be found
</script></body></html>');
$tagsToRemove=array();
foreach($object->getElementsByTagName("script") as $element)
{
    if($element instanceof  DOMElement)
    {
        if(!preg_match("/if\s*\(/i", $element->nodeValue))
        {
            $tagsToRemove[]=$element;
        }
    }
}
foreach($tagsToRemove as $element)
{
    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
}
echo $object->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Actually i'm using cURL to get the html.

Comment: @Avel can you share your complete HTML? but i think my  above example will work fine for your complete HTML as well